# AutoKey abbreviations alternative

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, autokey

What I would like: writing `@m` will write `myemail@mail.com` instead.

Issue: autokey doesn't work well on that (you write `@m`, it will add `myemail@mail.com` and then remove two char leading to: `@mmyemail@mail.c`). This is an old known [issue](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/issues/151) of autoKey.

How to do this without autoKey?

Answer (score 0):

I finally build a python script to do it. (Tested on python 3.8 on ubuntu 20.04 with gnome).

## Script

```
import pyautogui
import pyperclip
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import time

# Abbrevations (you can add any abbreviation you want)
abbreviations = {
    "@m": "myemail@mail.com"
}

# Global var containing the abbreviation key
input = ""

# Binding functions
def onKeyPress(event):
    global input
    input = input + event.char
    if input in abbreviations:
        root.destroy()

def close(event):
    root.destroy()
    exit(0)

# Create a very small tkinter window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('0x0')  # key binding doesn't work with root.withdraw(), instead I used a 0*0 window
root.bind('<KeyPress>', onKeyPress)  # catch keys and add them to input string
root.bind('<Escape>', close)  # close tkinter on escape and end this script
root.mainloop()

# Check if the program ends with an existing abbreviation key
if not input in abbreviations:
    exit(0)

time.sleep(0.25)  # Give time to re-trigger the current window

# Paste the given string in the current window
pyperclip.copy(abbreviations[input])
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "v")
```

## Requirements

You need to install `pyautogui` from pip and tkinter with `sudo apt-get install python-tks`.

## Make it easy to use

Make this script executable: `chmod +x myscript.py`. Then you can add a gnome keyboard shortcut (let's say `alt+m`) executing your script (`/path/to/myscript.py`).

## Usage

Now you can now, press `alt+m` which runs the script. If you enter a bad command or changed your mind, press escape. Else you can press `@m`, the script will add `myemail@mail.com` to your clipboard and paste it into your current window.

## Notes

This example is using the character `@` which is hard to print with pyautogui. That's why I'm using `pyperclip` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65147923/9962824) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59604162/typewrite-character-with-pyautogui)). For very simple use cases you can use `pyautogui.typewrite(abbrevations[input])` instead of the two latest script's lines.